# Pass a 2-D array as an argument to function

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

If I dont know the size of both the dimensions of array and want to print a matrix using the following code

```
    
    void printAnyMatrix(int (*A)[], int size_A, int size_B)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i<=size_A; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j<=size_B; j++)
               printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
           printf("\n");
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
```

Compiler gives

> error  cannot convert ‘int (*)[(((unsigned int)((int)size_B)) + 1)]’
>   to ‘int (*)[]’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void printAnyMatrix(int (*)[],
>   int, int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `template` feature for such problems:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int size_A, unsigned int size_B>
void printAnyMatrix(T  (&Arr)[size_A][size_B])
{       // any type^^  ^^^ pass by reference        
}
```

Now you can pass any 2D array to this function and the size will be automatically deduced in the form of `size_A` and `size_B`.

Examples:

```
int ai[3][9];
printAnyMatrix(ai);
...
double ad[18][18];
printAnyMatrix(ad);
```

Comment: no matching function for call to ‘printAnyMatrix(int [(((unsigned int)((int)size_A)))][(((unsigned int)((int)size_B)))])
note: candidate is:
note: template<class T, unsigned int size_A, unsigned int size_B> void printAnyMatrix(T (&)[(size_A)][(size_B)])

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the signature: a pointer is simpler to read by humans.

You also have an error in the loops: it's less then, not less or equal.

```
void printAnyMatrix(int *A, int size_A, int size_B)<br />
{
   for (int i = 0; i<size_A; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j<size_B; j++)
           printf("%d ", A[i*size_B + j]);
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: cannot convert ‘int (*)[(((unsigned int)((int)size_B)) + 1)]’ to ‘int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void printAnyMatrix(int*, int, int)

Comment: That means you are calling prinAnyMatrix with the wrong argument for int*. It appears the argument you're calling with is actually an int, not an int* (for the 1st position)

Comment: int matrix[size_A][size_B], size_A, size_B;
I am calling printAnyMatrix(matrix, size_A, size_B);

Comment: If matrix is int*, then matrix[a] is int, and matrix[a][b] is compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print any matrix, maybe you will need to print both statically and dynamically allocated matrices. Function for statically-allocated matrices will look like the following

```
template <class T, int size_A, int size_B>
void printAnyMatrix(T (&A)[size_A][size_B])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < size_A; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < size_B; j++)
           std::cout<<A[i][j]<<' ';
       std::cout<<'\n';
   }
   std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Function for dynamically-allocated matrices:

```
template <class T>
void printAnyMatrix(T **A, int size_A, int size_B)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < size_A; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < size_B; j++)
           cout<<A[i][j]<<' ';
       cout<<'\n';
   }
   std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

You can have both of them in the same translation unit, compiler will pick the one that fits to your matrix. (note: for statically-allocated matrices you need one parameter, while for dynamically-allocated - three)

Please consider using `cout` instead of `printf` if you work in C++. It is overloaded for all basic types, while `printf` needs you to declare the type explicitly.

If you still have compiler errors, please show the declaration of your matrix.

Comment: There is no conversion from `int[m][n]` to `int**`. Calling your function with a 2D array will result in a compiler error.